# Jenkins email template (groovy) with custom variable is always printed in the email

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, email-ext, jenkins-groovy

We are using plugin `email-ext` in combination with `Jenkins-pipeline` for sending emails (groovy-based template). Jenkins runs multiple jobs (all those jobs are sending emails on failure) and for some jobs additional information is needed in the email. For a few jobs this information is unnecessary and therefore this custom variable row should not be present. In the jobs where this row is unnecessary we didn't defined this custom var.

With an if statement in the groovy email template we're experiencing that this custom variable is always present in the email.

```
<%
def envOverrides = it.getAction('org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl').getOverriddenEnvironment()
if (${envOverrides["custom1"]} != null) { %>
<tr>
    <td><b>Custom variable:</b></td>
    <td>${envOverrides["custom1"]}</td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

In the jenkinsfile this custom var is defined for some like this (and not present in the jobs where this is not needed):

```
env.custom1 = "dummy_value"
```

In our case this row is printed everytime, regardless if the custom var has a value or not. So f.e. if the custom var is set it looks like:

`Custom variable:   dummy_value`

And if the custom var is **not** set it prints:

`Custom variable:   null`

Expectation is that this row is not present in the email. What do we do wrong? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Once I've found out that the envOverrides returns a map, the solution was made fast:

```
<%
def envOverrides = it.getAction('org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl').getOverriddenEnvironment()
if (envOverrides.containsKey('custom1') && "${envOverrides['custom1']} != '') { %>
<tr>
    <td><b>Custom variable:</b></td>
    <td>${envOverrides['custom1']}</td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

With this adjustment the complete row isn't printed in the email when it's not defined in the jenkinsfile or when the value is empty.